# How do I send scanresults from broadcastreceiver to service

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver, wifimanager

I have a broadcastreceiver created in my Service class.
It is set to react to this action: WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION

So basically everytime I do a method call of wifi.startScan(); , and the results become available, the broadcastreceiver's onReceive method does its thing.

My issue is that I need to process those scan results and its likely not good practice to do so much in the broadcastreceiver. I want to do all the calculations back in my service class but I need to somehow access the ScanResults.

Any sort of help with this? As it is much needed.

Here is a simplified version of my code conveying the purpose of my broadcastreceiver:

Snippet from my Service class:

```java
        IntentFilter i = new IntentFilter();
        i.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION); //reacts to the scan results being available

        registerReceiver(mybroadcast,i);

        wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if(!wifi.isWifiEnabled()){ // if wifi is not enabled
                toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wifi is off. Please turn it on.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                //wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
                //startActivity(backIntent);

         }

         else
         {
                wifi.startScan(); //what the receiver is going to react to
         }
```

Code for my receiver:

```java
private final BroadcastReceiver mybroadcast = new BroadcastReceiver() {
           @Override
           public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                //gets the scan results
                wifi = (WifiManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                List<ScanResult> scans = wifi.getScanResults();
                     // do some work here...
                   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding an handler to service for ex:

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler() {

    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        String aResponse = msg.getData().getString("message");

        if ((null != aResponse)) {

            // ALERT MESSAGE
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Server Response: " + aResponse, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {

            // ALERT MESSAGE
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Not Got Response From Server.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

    }
};
```

And send a message to it in OnReceive of your BroadcastReceiver:

```
   Message msgObj = handler.obtainMessage();
   Bundle b = new Bundle();
   b.putString("message", msg);
   msgObj.setData(b);
   handler.sendMessage(msgObj);
```